# Is setting signal values to unitialized acceptable?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, intel-fpga, quartus

To achieve something in my VHDL code I'm currently doing:

```
tmpOutput <= "UUUUUUUU";
```

Is that seen as something wrong entirely? Also, can this bring problems when synthesizing the design?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'U' is not undefined, but uninitialized. It is perfectly legal, but *weird* since a signal would logically not go from uninitialized to a value back to uninitialized.

It may be better to use 'X', which is unknown or '-' which is don't care. As for what a synthesis tool will do with it, it will either consider it as don't care or the same as '0'.

Comment: So if I'm checking if a signal is unitialized to do something or not, then when sinthesizing the behaviour will not be consistent right?

Comment: I'd say no. Although it may be consistent for a tool (like always considered false). Checking a signal for anything else than '0' or '1' should only be used in simulation. There is also the function std_match to compare signals while taking into account when bits are '-', 'H', 'L', etc.

Comment: Oh okay, so pretty much never check for something different than 0 or 1 if you're planning to synthesize the design. Thanks!